# How to create mathematics mind set like that?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, macros, pgfmath, mindmaps

[image]

How to create math mind set like this image?

Answer (score 2):

this looks like a flowchart. You can find examples over here https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/
You can also use the normal mathematic-mode of Latex inside the boxes.

I make my charts like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.95\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[%Settings
%node distance= vertical and horizontal
node distance=1cm and 1cm,
rounded corners,
font=\small,
>=stealth'
]
%nodes
\node[draw, rectangle, align=left, text width = 0.2 \textwidth]         (first)     {long text, which describes the first step};
\node[draw, rectangle, right =of first, text width = 0.2 \textwidth] (second)   {2. step};
\node[draw, rectangle, right =of second, text width = 0.2 \textwidth]  (third)  {3. step};
%Connections
\draw[->] (first.east)--(second);
\draw[->] (second.east)--(third);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\label{fig:flowchart}
\caption{flow chart diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Sorry for that, I added the packages and put it in the right order (documentclass, ...)

Comment: usepackage for this code??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Your `MWE` should start from `\documentclass{....}` and end with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

Always fun make this kind of flowchart with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{equCol}{HTML}{92CDDC}
\definecolor{diamCol}{HTML}{FCACB7}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%problem
\node[draw=gray!50!equCol,thick,rounded corners,fill=equCol,align=center] (equation) 
{Resolucion de l'équacion\\
$az^2 + bz + c = 0$\\
$(a\in \mathbb{R}^+);\ (b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^2$};

%delta
\node[below= of equation,draw=gray,thick,inner sep=10pt,rounded corners] (delta)
{$\Delta=b^2 - 4ac$};
\tikzset{diaSt/.style={diamond,aspect=1.5,inner sep=5pt,fill=diamCol,draw=gray!50!diamCol,thick}}

%cases
\node[below left=and 15ex of delta,diaSt]       (caseMin)   {$\Delta<0$};
\node[below right=and 15ex of delta,diaSt]      (caseMaj)   {$\Delta>0$};
\node[diaSt] at ($(caseMin)!0.5!(caseMaj)$)         (caseEq)        {$\Delta=0$};

%solutions
\tikzset{solSt/.style={draw=diamCol,thick,align=center,rounded corners}} 
%<0
\node[below=30ex of  caseMin,solSt] (solMin) 
{l'èquation admet\\
duex solucions complexes conjuguées\\
$S=\{z_1;z_2\}$ où\\
$z_1=\dfrac{-b+i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}$ et $z_2=\dfrac{-b-i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}$};   
%=0
\node[below=10ex of  caseEq,solSt] (solEq)
{l'èquation admet\\
une solucion réelle double\\
$S=\{z\}$ où\\
$z=-\dfrac{b}{2a}$};    
%>0
\node[below=30ex of  caseMaj,solSt] (solMaj)
{l'èquation admet\\
duex solucions réelles distinctes\\
$S=\{z_1;z_2\}$ où\\
$z_1=\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}$ et $z_2=\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}$};

%arrows
\foreach \start/\finish in 
{equation/delta,delta/caseMin,delta/caseMaj,delta/caseEq,caseMin/solMin,caseEq/solEq,caseMaj/solMaj}
\draw[->,red!70!black,very thick](\start) -- (\finish);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing!!